# Repeat the same subreport on a each page JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a main report that contain a subreport in a header band, and I need that this subreport prints on each page of my main report.

The problem is that the subreport is only printing once, although this report has 2 or more pages.

The subreport only have an image and a label.

Comment: You should put your sub report in detail band.

Comment: The subreport has to be necessarily on header band for each page.

Comment: In header, you can not repeat sub report values. If you write something in the header once, it will print on every page on the header.

Comment: page header is in every page (as is page footer) so you'll need to put your subreport in one of those to get it to appear on every page